# Tomcat7 is listening port but not processes requests

Tags: server, apache2, tomcat7

Im trying to run my web server in VPS based on ubuntu 14.04. As i tried before on other systems i can check if my tomcat is fine, by going to _http://myIp:8080 and see "It works" index page, but not this time. And honestly im going crazy because i cant figure whats wrong.
 
I installed tomcat just with command

```
 apt-get install tomcat7
```

All was fine. I checked that port `8080` is open and went to `_http://myIp:8080` - and nothing happens. I can't see 404 (that would mean that tomcat managed request) and I cant see "connection failed" (that would mean, that port is closed or thmthng). Connection is just hangs.

I tried to change tomcat port to 1666 (of course, i turned off ufw firewall)
Reloaded server, and ROOT deployment was fine again. But i still cant get anything from my server (answer or error) _http://myIp:1666

[Here](http://pastebin.com/qnvrzYNt) is catalina start log.

And there is nothing except deployment logs.

I have reinstalled tomcat couple of times, but still no result.

#### UPD

i killed my old VPS and created new one. installed tomcat 7 via apt-get again so he is listening  to 8080. and here is my grep result

```
netstat -na | grep -e 1666 -e 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

OMG doez it means that tomcat binds to ipV6 and i trying to get my page via ipV4?

#### UPD2

I created senenv.sh for tomcat with

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true"
```

and now my tomcat listening to ipv4 tcp. But still no result. When i trying to connect myIP:8080 there is nothing happens/

```
-na | grep -e 1666 -e 8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

#### UPD3

IT F***g works.
 I missed why,  i just spend 10 more minutes in internet after restarting tomcat, trying to find something to solve my problem. And then i tried to get myIP:8080 again - and i saw "It works" index page.

Comment: How did you checked the port is open? where is the socket port binded? localhost? *? your ip?
Can you post the output of "ss -lntp | grep -e 1666 -e 8080" or "netstat -na | grep -e 1666 -e 8080"?

Comment: updated my question. I checked with ping.eu - this is good site for such sings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Core problem was that tomcat listens to ipv6 tcp port. I tried to get to my page via ipv4 adress. So i created setenv.sh in /usr/share/tomcat7/bin with single line

> JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true"

and restarted tomcat via

```
sudo bash tomcat7 restart
```

in /etc/init.d
Then checked my port again with

> netstat -na | grep -e 8080

and saw, that ipv4 is using now

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

And after few minutes i could get to my index.html

Thanx  @Idaho06 for

```
netstat -na | grep -e 8080
```

I would never found problem without it

Comment: i think it must be `setenv.sh`, not setenc.sh

Comment: @ Ferenjito Thanx! Fixed.

Comment: @Asprelis can you please share why binding to ipv6 can be a problem? In my case a TCP connection is setup but server doesn't respond back. I would like to dig deeper.